# How to insert record into Join table in EF Core

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm new to Entity Framework Core code first (using EF Core 6.07). I am attempting to insert a record into a join table with two columns, but I am getting an error of **"InvalidOperationException: The value of 'MovieGenre.MovieId' is unknown when attempting to save changes. This is because the property is also part of a foreign key for which the principal entity in the relationship is not known."** The join table is as follows:

```
    public class MovieGenre
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Movie Id required")]
        public int MovieId { get; set; }
        public Movies Movies { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Genre Id required")]
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    }
```

Its two columns reference the ID columns of the following tables:

```
    public class Movies
    {
        [Key]
        public int MovieId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title cannot be Null")]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(256)")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
        public string Overview { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(512)")]
        public string Tagline { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
        public decimal Budget { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
        public decimal Revenue { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(2084)")]
        public string ImdbUrl { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(2084)")]
        public string TmdbUrl { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(2084)")]
        public string PosterUrl { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(2084)")]
        public string BackdropUrl { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(64)")]
        public string OriginalLanguage { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2(7)")]

        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

        public int RunTime { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(5,2)")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2(7)")]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2(7)")]
        public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        
        public List<MovieCrew> MovieCrews { get; set; }

        public List<MovieCast> MovieCasts { get; set; }

        public List<MovieGenre> MovieGenres { get; set; }

        public List<Trailer> Trailers { get; set; }

        public List<Favorite> Favorites { get; set; }

        public List<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }

        public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class Genre
    {
        [Key]
        public int GenreId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name cannot be null")]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(64)")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<MovieGenre> MovieGenres { get; set; }
    }
```

I have also set up my custom DB context file to manually specify the foreign key relationships between the two primary tables and the join table. Also, I have added the two foreign key columns in the join table as a composite primary key.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Movies>()
                .HasMany(x => x.MovieGenres).WithOne(x => x.Movies).HasForeignKey(x => x.MovieId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Genre>()
                .HasMany(x => x.MovieGenres).WithOne(x => x.Genre).HasForeignKey(x => x.GenreId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<MovieGenre>()
                .HasKey(o => new { o.MovieId, o.GenreId });
        }
```

I am attempting to insert data into the join table using a model, controller, and view. I am able to successfully insert into the Movies and Genre tables, but when I try to do so for the join table, MovieGenre, I am getting the error mentioned in bold above. The MovieID and GenreID I am attempting to insert into the join table already exist in the Movie and Genre tables. Can someone please help me learn what I am doing wrong?

Edit: Adding the code I am using to insert into the cross-reference table.

IRepositoryAsync:

```
using System;
namespace Antra.Movie.Core.Contracts.Repositories
{
    public interface IRepositoryAsync<T> where T: class
    {
        Task<int> InsertAsync(T Entity);
        Task<int> UpdateAsync(T Entity);
        Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id);
        Task<int> DeleteAsync(int id);
        Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync();
    }
}
```

IMovieGenreRepositoryAsync:

```
using System;
using Antra.Movie.Core.Entities;
namespace Antra.Movie.Core.Contracts.Repositories
{
    public interface IMovieGenreRepositoryAsync:IRepositoryAsync<MovieGenre>
    {
    }
}
```

BaseRepositoryAsync:

```
using System;
using Antra.Movie.Core.Contracts.Repositories;
using Antra.Movie.Infrastructure.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Antra.Movie.Infrastructure.Repositories
{
    public class BaseRepositoryAsync<T>:IRepositoryAsync<T> where T: class
    {

        MovieDbContext db;

        public BaseRepositoryAsync(MovieDbContext _context)
        {
            db = _context;
        }

        public async Task<int> DeleteAsync(int id)
        {
            var entity = await db.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
            db.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
            return await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            return await db.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            var entity = await db.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
            return entity;
        }

        public async Task<int> InsertAsync(T Entity)
        {
            await db.Set<T>().AddAsync(Entity);
            return await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        }

        public async Task<int> UpdateAsync(T Entity)
        {
            db.Entry<T>(Entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            return await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

MovieGenreRepositoryAsync:

```
using System;
using Antra.Movie.Core.Contracts.Repositories;
using Antra.Movie.Core.Entities;
using Antra.Movie.Infrastructure.Data;

namespace Antra.Movie.Infrastructure.Repositories
{
    public class MovieGenreRepositoryAsync : BaseRepositoryAsync<MovieGenre>, IMovieGenreRepositoryAsync
    {
        public MovieGenreRepositoryAsync(MovieDbContext _context):base(_context)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

IMovieGenreServiceAsync:

```
using System;
using Antra.Movie.Core.Model;

namespace Antra.Movie.Infrastructure.Services
{
    public interface IMovieGenreServiceAsync
    {
        Task<int> InsertMovieGenre(MovieGenreModel _movieGenreModel);
    }
}
```

MovieGenreServiceAsync:

```
using System;
using Antra.Movie.Core.Contracts.Repositories;
using Antra.Movie.Core.Entities;
using Antra.Movie.Core.Model;

namespace Antra.Movie.Infrastructure.Services
{
    public class MovieGenreServiceAsync:IMovieGenreServiceAsync
    {
        IMovieGenreRepositoryAsync MovieGenreRepo;
        public MovieGenreServiceAsync(IMovieGenreRepositoryAsync _movieGenreRepo)
        {
            MovieGenreRepo = _movieGenreRepo;
        }

        public async Task<int> InsertMovieGenre(MovieGenreModel _movieGenreModel)
        {
            MovieGenre moviegenreentity = new MovieGenre()
            {
                MovieId = _movieGenreModel.MovieId,
                GenreId = _movieGenreModel.GenreId
            };
            return await MovieGenreRepo.InsertAsync(moviegenreentity);
        }
    }
}
```

MovieGenreModel:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Antra.Movie.Core.Entities;

namespace Antra.Movie.Core.Model
{
    public class MovieGenreModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Movie Id required")]
        public int MovieId { get; set; }
        public Movies Movies { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Genre Id required")]
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }

        public MovieGenreModel()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

MovieGenreController:

```
using System;
using Antra.Movie.Core.Model;
using Antra.Movie.Infrastructure.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace Antra.Movie.WebMVC.Controllers
{
    public class MovieGenreController:Controller
    {
        IGenreServiceAsync genreServiceAsync;
        IMovieServiceAsync movieServiceAsync;
        IMovieGenreServiceAsync movieGenreServiceAsync;
        public MovieGenreController(IGenreServiceAsync _genreService, IMovieServiceAsync _movieService, IMovieGenreServiceAsync _moviegenreService)
        {
            genreServiceAsync = _genreService;
            movieServiceAsync = _movieService;
            movieGenreServiceAsync = _moviegenreService;
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            ViewBag.GenreSelect = new SelectList(await genreServiceAsync.GetAllGenres(), "Id", "Name");

            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(MovieGenreModel _model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                await movieGenreServiceAsync.InsertMovieGenre(_model);
            }
            return View(_model);
        }
    }
}
```

Create.cshtml view for the MovieGenreController:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@model GenreModel
<form method="post" asp-controller="MovieGenre" asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="GenreName">GenreId</label>
        <input type="text" name="Name" class="form-control" id="GenreName" placeholder="Enter genre name">
        <span asp-validation-for="Name"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="GenreName">MovieId</label>
        <input type="text" name="Name" class="form-control" id="GenreName" placeholder="Enter genre name">
        <span asp-validation-for="Name"></span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I've removed the conflicting RDBMS tags here; please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Tagging multiple conflicting technologies makes your question unclear and thus *harder* to answer. It is also unlikely to get your question "more views" and likely to have the opposite effect, where only users who know *all* the RDBMS you have (mis)tagged will entertain the question; that is often a very small portion of the user base. Please [edit] your question to retag the correct RDBMS.

Comment: Gotcha. I have retagged with Azure Data studio, which is the RDBMS I am currently using for my project.

Comment: Azure Data Studio isn't an RDBMS, it's an IDE like application, that can be used with SQL Server (and other Microsoft products that use T-SQL), and PostgreSQL, @nunya . Tagging ADS isn't helpful.

Comment: please include the code where you are trying to insert values into your cross-reference table

Comment: @Vasya. I have gone ahead and added the code I am using to insert values.

Answer (score 0):

First of all You don't need mapping table as `MovieGenre` unless you don't have any specific properties in it.
Also you don't need to do anything in the `DbContext` if you use code first, the mapping and everything you need will be created automatically except the `DbSets`.
So I would recommend:

In the context

```
public virtual DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
```

Movies

```
public class Movie
{
   public Movie()
   {
       this.Genres = new HashSet<Genre>();
   }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Other Props....

    public virtual ICollection<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

Genres

```
public class Genre
{
    public Genre()
    {
        this.Movies = new HashSet<Movie>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Other Props....

    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

No need to add separates,

```
var genre = new Genre { Name = "Action" };
var movie = new Movie { Name = "MovieName" };
movie.Genres.Add(genre);

await context.AddAsync(movie);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Edit

Queries

```
//movie by name
var movieByName = db.Movies.Include(x => x.Genres).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name = "MovieName");
var genres = movieByName.Genres; //Genres related to The movie

//movies by genre
var moviesByGenres = context.Movies.Include(x => x.Genres).Where(x => x.Genres.Any(x => x.Name == "Action")).ToList();

//genre by name
var genre = context.Genres.Include(x => x.Movies).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name = "Action");
var movies = genre.Movies; //Movies related to the Genre
```

Edit

Adding Movie with existing Genre

```
var movie = new Movie { Name = "MovieName" };
var genre = context.Genre.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Action");
movie.Genres.Add(genre);

await context.AddAsync(movie);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How does EF core associate a given MovieName to a given Genre? For example, if I enter a user input record into the Movie table and Genre table using a model+view+controller, how does the join table associate a given movie record with an existing genre record, or a given genre record with an existing movie record?

Comment: You can get the Genre from the database and add it to the Movie, so the Genre will not be added again to the database, only as a reference to the Movie.